# Write a value for maximum/minimum between two values

Tags: r

I have a two-column matrix and I want to produce a new matrix/data.frame where Col N has 1 if is maximum, 0 otherwise (they are never equal). This is my attempt:

```
testM <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 1,1,5), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
>testM
    V1  V2
1   1   2
2   3   1
3   1   5

apply(data.frame(testM), 1, function(row) ifelse(max(row[1],row[2]),1,0))
```

I expect to have:

```
0 1
1 0
0 1
```

because of the 0,1 parameters in max() function, but I just get

```
[1] 1 1 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `max` returns the value of the max of `row[1]` and `row[2]`, and it is positive in your example, thus considered as `TRUE`. Change to `ifelse(row[1] > row[2],1,0)`

Comment: Maybe also `(testM == matrixStats::rowMaxs(testM)) + 0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can perform arithmetic on Booleans in R! Just check if an element in each row is equal to it's max value and multiply by 1.

```
t(apply(testM, 1, function(row) 1*(row == max(row))))
```

Answer (score 5):

Or using `pmax`

```
testM <- matrix(c(1,2,3, 1,1,5), ncol = 2, byrow = T)

--(testM==pmax(testM[,1],testM[,2]))

     V1 V2
[1,]  0  1
[2,]  1  0
[3,]  0  1
```

Comment: You"ll probably need to add `+0` in order to make it binary

Comment: @DavidArenburg i have double minus "--" before your edit... now its not work)

Comment: I like the `pmax` approach but the `--` is only suited for code golf, in my opinion.

Comment: @Batanichek, code golfing means solving a programming task with the shortest possible code (often compromising readability, which I think is important when it comes to production code)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Yes may be, its like `+0` or `*1`and not always easy to understand without comments

Answer (score 4):

You can use `max.col` and `col` to produce a logical matrix:

```
res <- col(testM) == max.col(testM)
res
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
```

If you want it as 0/1, you can do:

```
res <- as.integer(col(testM) == max.col(testM)) # this removes the dimension
dim(res) <- dim(testM) # puts the dimension back
res
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    1
[2,]    1    0
[3,]    0    1
```